# Who built the Ilmarin?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, valar

From my other questions you can conclude that I am searching for a palace/great building to re-create in a 3D model with blender. I have chosen one now, [Ilmarin](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ilmarin) which is the Mansion of Varda and Manwë atop of the Taniquetil mountain in Valinor. As reference I am using [this](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140417111429/thegioitolkien/images/f/f7/Ilmarin.jpg) art, but this isn't enough to make up the architectural style of the building which leads me to my question

**Did Manwë built the mansion himself or did he get someone else (Elves?) to do it?**

**What Architectural style would have been used?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Silmarillion chapter 1, Manwe occupied Taniquetil after the destruction of the Lamps and their move to Valinor, but *before* the awakening of the Elves.

The Elves therefore *did not* build Manwe's halls; it's possible that Aule built them but Tolkien doesn't say.

Their atchitectural style would therefore be described as "Valarin", but again this is something that Tolkien doesn't elaborate much on, if at all.

Comment: In History of Middle Earth (HoME) Chapter 10, Tolkien says that the Valar raised the Pelori mountain range and then set Manwe's throne upon it.

Comment: That will be really hard in blender, just sayin'.